# Windows XP VM or Windows 7 VM?

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, windows-xp

I've got an HP laptop with 750 GB ROM,4 GB RAM,a dual-core processor with 2.4 GHz and it's running Ubuntu 12.04.
I want to use VirtualBox to make a Windows XP/7 Virtual Machine,but I don't know which one of them is better for gaming.
I think Windows XP SP3 (64-bit) would run almost any game perfectly with 3512 or 3252 MB of RAM allocated to it,because I don't really care about how my VM looks,I want top performances.
Windows 7 is very good too,but it consumes more resources so...What do you think?What should I choose?

Comment: Depends on the games you want to play, most new games require Windows 7. So for me that would be the choice. But it really depends on the games.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaming in a Virtual box will not give you a good experience. 3D resources (e.g. GPU RAM) will be shared with your 12.04 host. Some games will probably work, like Minecraft. But running heavy programs like recent DirectX games will not work.

So my suggestion will be to run a XP Virtual machine for old games and dual boot Windows 7 for recent games.